# Generate a zero matrix from a vector with None Shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am given a tensor of Shape `[None,1,None]` (First None being the Batch size, corresponding to e.g. `[1,1,28]`) and I want to generate a `tf.zeros_like` matrix of form `[None,1,None,None]` where the last two Nones are the same (so in the example being `[1,1,28,28]`).

Lets say d is the vector of shapes `[None,1,None]`
What I tried was:

```
z = tf.zeros_like(tf.broadcast_to(d, tf.concat([d.shape, d.shape[-1:]], axis=0)), tf.int32)
```

The idea being: I concat the the shape of d with the last shape of d in order to keep the sizes correct, to then broadcast d to these shapes to use the result of that broadcast to generate `zeros_like`. I understand that just `tf.zeros` does not work in this case, since it does not work with `None` shapes. 
This approach fails though, resulting in this error:
`Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [<NOT CONVERTIBLE TO TENSOR>, <NOT CONVERTIBLE TO TENSOR>] that don't all match.`

Comment: Pls add a working code example for your problem.

Comment: You mean with initializiation? As said it only works if I use: `d= tf.convert_to_tensor([[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0]]])` (so shapes are fully known) I am looking for a way to have it work for Partially known shapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a three-dimensional tensor `a` and want to make a four-dimensional tensor `b` filled with zeros, where the first three dimensions of `b` are the same as `a` and the fourth dimension is the same as the third dimension of `a`, you can just do:

```
s = tf.shape(a)
s = tf.concat([s, s[-1:]], axis=0)
b = tf.zeros(s, a.dtype)
```

Comment: actually, this is way better than my solution. Thank you!